# how i use groovy to insert a node which has attribute and value

Tags: groovy

there is a simple xml, for example:

```
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
'<root>
    <one a1="uno!"/>
    <two>Some text!</two>
 </root>' )
```

how can i insert a node

```
<three type='c'>2334</three>
```

into root?

i have use this way to insert

```
rootNode.appendNode{three(type:'c') 2334}
rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(rootNode)
```

but it return exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below script should give you desired result:

change from yours: `three (type:'c', 2334)`

```
import groovy.xml.*
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText('<root><one a1="uno!"/><two>Some text!</two></root>' )
rootNode.appendNode {
    three (type:'c', 2334)
}
def newRootNode = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {mkp.yield rootNode}.toString()
println newRootNode
```

Output:
`<root><one a1='uno!'></one><two>Some text!</two><three type='c'>2334</three></root>`